# How to fix this MySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query as follows.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `vi_listings` 
 WHERE `list_id` IN ( SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(`rel_listings`,
                                            4,
                                            CHAR_LENGTH(`rel_listings`)
                                           ),
                                     "}",
                                     "") as listings 
                        FROM `vi_list_tags` 
                       WHERE `tag_name`="Hospitals"
                    )
```

If I run this query its shows only one raw instead of two.

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(`rel_listings`,4,CHAR_LENGTH(`rel_listings`)),"}","") as listings 
  FROM `vi_list_tags` 
 WHERE `tag_name`="Hospitals"
```

The above query returns the value like **2,1** and both ID are present in the table.

If I run the query as below it shows two rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `vi_listings` WHERE `list_id` IN(2,1)
```

What is the error in my first query?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the types, ID is an int and your subquery is varchar

Comment: @esdebon if it is like that,then the query will not show any results. right? as there is no id like '2,1'

Comment: It will take the first one then.

Comment: What is the actual data in `rel_listings`? are you trying to cause a comma-separated string to operate inside an `IN()`? (that won't work - it will be treated as a single value)

Comment: in rel_listings the value is like **{0,2,1}**

Comment: I thinking use a CAST, but the final result is VARCHAR

Comment: Share sample data -> Best guess: @MichaelBerkowski has solved your problem